# Java floating point computations behavior differences

Tags: java, java-8, precision, jit, java-17

In the context of a scientific computing pipeline implemented in Java, we are using a LeastSquare optimizer from Apache Commons math 3.6.1 and experience strange numerical differences between Java 8 (jdk8u322-b06), Java and Java 17.

We noticed differences after migration to Java 17 (currently using 17.0.5.)

I can reproduce the different behavior between Java 8 and Java 17 in a "simple" unit test without involving the full computing pipeline so all problems that could come from the data loading  or multi threading part are excluded.

In JDK 17 the strict floating point semantics has been restored but the results is fully different compared to Java 8 compiled or interpreted. In this case actually the least square optimizer does not converge while it does in the Java 8 case.

An important point is that all these results are fully reproducible to the last digit, they are fully predictable on each platform configuration.

I also but this time in the full pipeline execution observed that I can reproduce numerical difference on Java 8 itself depending if the code is interpreted or compiled (at C2 level or C1 I did not investigated yet)

I am really puzzled and would like to know if this are known/documented behaviors or if this is a bug in the JDK 8 platform or JDK 17 ?
Does anyone observed such issues ?

Thanks for any hints !

**EDIT**

I cannot provide here a simple code snippet to reproduce the issue. But I extracted the necessary part of the code to reproduce the behavior in a GitHub repository. Disclaimer : I'am not the original author of the code.

Steps to reproduce:

- git clone https://github.com/gjevardat/ReproduceFloatingPointBug
- Run the unit test named TimeSeriesModelFitterBugTest
  I ran it in eclipse as a Junit5 test.

To see the difference of behavior just switch the java.version property from 1.8 to 17 in the pom.xml.

I can pinpoint the location in Apache math commons were the code diverge:
In the class LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer of Apache Math commmons 3.6.1 (line 453)

```
  double actRed = -1.0;
      if (0.1 * currentCost < previousCost) {
          double r = currentCost / previousCost;
          actRed = 1.0 - r * r;
      }
```

At iteration 17 actRed becomes 0 because r==1 in Java 17 while it is slightly positive in Java 8
Because of the value being 0, later (line 533) the non convergenceException is thrown

```
 if (FastMath.abs(actRed) <= TWO_EPS &&
     preRed <= TWO_EPS && ratio <= 2.0) {
         throw new ConvergenceException(LocalizedFormats.TOO_SMALL_COST_RELATIVE_TOLERANCE,
                                               costRelativeTolerance);
            }
```

Comment: Could explain where the error is?  For example, what result do you see, and what result to you expect to see?  I realize the arrays are large but pointing out what values (at least a few of them) are wrong might help folks debug on their own end.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: Yes I will do this, for that I need to rework a bit the code such that I can reproduce in a minimal unit test.

Comment: @Progman Just added a link to the reproductible example.

Comment: @greg Please add your code to the question itself, not on an external site.

Comment: @Progman It's not a simple code snippet there are multiple classes involved so I'am not sure how to proceed on stackoverlow as I do not see any import zipped or similar button